# Prevent duplication in result list when comparing and matching two lists of objects

Tags: javascript, html

I am comparing two object in javascript, if that matches then make the color red, if not keep it black. However, it returns two lines of information rather than one.

In the following result, I expect to see first two element red the last one black. However it returns and writes two rows, rather than one row.

```
$.each(aut.AssociatedwellList, function(k,mano) { 
    $.each(aut.WellList, function(j,mango) { 
        if(mano.WellName === mango.WellName) {
            wellNameList += '<li style="color:red;"><div>'+ mango.WellName+'</div></li>';
        } else {
            wellNameList += '<li ><div>'+ mango.WellName+'</div></li>';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: compare by reference not by value...

Comment: Could you please illustrate?

Comment: The code you posted here is not included in that jsfiddle you linked.

Comment: If you want help with a problem you should provide a _minimal_ working sample of the issue.

Comment: Please check my jfiddle code

Comment: @casillas again, the nested `$.each()` code you posted here is nowhere to be found in the linked jsfiddle.

Comment: @Pointy, please check one updated  http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/19/

Comment: @casillas your inner loop **always** adds an `<li>`.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using <li> in my case?

Comment: I want to display user matched item and as well unmatched items. If items match, highlight with red color, if not leave it black color

Comment: @casillas Sorry, it appears I misread the question.

Comment: @Paul, sorry, most likely I did not deliver question in detail and make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using nested loops improperly. You can use the Array `.some()` method to see which entries in the "well list" are also in the "associated well list" (which is what I *think* you're trying to do):

```
        $.each(aut.WellList, function(k,mano){
            if(aut.AssociatedwellList.some(function(w) { return w.WellName === mano.WellName; }))
                {
                wellNameList += '<li style="color:red;"><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></li>';
                }
                else
                {
             wellNameList += '<li ><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></li>';
                }
            });
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/21/)

(Note that the problem has nothing whatsoever to do with the comparison operation itself. The problem was that the inner loop would *always* add an `<li>` to the list.)

Comment: @ Pointy, thanks a lot for your effort and explanation, However, in the solution that you provided, we do not display unmatched items in black. We only display matched item in red.

Comment: @casillas I see black ones when I do it. oh wait, sorry, I forgot to update the fiddle. [Try this one.](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/21/)

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I see black items as well. I have marked your answer.

Comment: do you have any idea for the following issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287632/disable-tab-button-to-expands-accordion